# i need to click on check box named sign up for newsletter using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**I need to click on check box named sign up for newsletter using selenium webdriver in java**

```
<div class="input-box">
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="Sign Up for Newsletter" value="1" id="is_subscribed" class="checkbox"><label for="is_subscribed"><span></span>Sign Up for Newsletter</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try and what was the problem with it?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("is_subscribed")).click();
  System.out.println("The output of isselected is" driver.findElement(By.id("is_subscribed")).isDisplayed());

Comment: i have tried above code but cannot click on it.

Comment: @kunalsoni Is it throwing any error? Or just skipping, checking the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the checkbox element using findelements method and xpath locator and store it in a list as below and use the for loop to traverse through the list and if condition to check whether the checkbox is selected and perform select using click.

```
List <WebElement> checkbox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Your xpath here"));

for(WebElement e:checkbox)
{
if(e.getAttribute("value").equals("1")){
e.click;
}
}
```

Or as below

```
 List <WebElement> checkbox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Your xpath here"));

for(WebElement e:checkbox)
{
if(!e.isSelected){
e.click;
}
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

use cssselector select the node ,then call the click event on your select node.

Comment: how? can you tell me please

Comment: WebElement oCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value="1]"));
     oCheckBox.click();

Comment: i have tried this but there two check box in the page with the same value

Comment: I use chrome developer and use copy cssselector to choise a node. you should use By.cssSelector("the file you have copied").

Answer (score 0):

U can try this

WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.id("object's Id here"));
checkbox.click();